# Using JTree with C# and Test Complete

Tags: c#, jtree, testcomplete

I am writing a test which accesses a JTree via test complete and C#.  I have attached an image.  Unfortunately, for company confidentiality I had to black out some of the text.  But it is basically the following:

Routing Rules

- Level 2 branches

  - level 3 selections

I get the JTree into a C# var (call it "tree").  I can easily expand and collapse by doing

```
tree["DblClickItem"]("Routing Rules");  // expand/collapse top branch
tree["DblClickItem"]("Routing Rules|Level 2 branches");  // expand/collapse second-level
tree["ClickItem"]("Routing Rules|Level 2 branches|level 3 selections") // select item
```

that works fine.  But when I try to determine whether something is expanded or not, like this

```
var expanded = tree["wExpanded"]("Routing Rules");
```

this gives an exception

- ```
    _innerException {"Unable to find the object wExpanded(\"Routing Rules\"). See Details for additional information.\r\n<html><body><p>The object with the specified attributes does not exist.</p><p style=\"margin-top: 12px;\"><a href=\"aqa-help://2202\">Possible causes of the error</a></p></body></html>"} System.Exception {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException}
  ```

this appears to be how this web site says to do it:

https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/app-objects/specific-tasks/standard/tree-view/checking-item-state.html#Expanded

Am I doing something wrong?  Or can I not assign the value to a "var" and must use it in an if() statement?

Answer (score 1):

C#Script (which is not C#) is described as a "legacy language" specifically designed for deprecated functionality and is [not recommended for new projects](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/reference/language/csscript.html).

The "*wExpanded*" property is obsolete and only included in TestComplete for backward compatibility. Furthermore it is designed specifically for win32TreeView objects and not JTree objects.

It would be better to use the *Item* object - it's designed to be a generic interface across a variety of application toolkits, and it has an "*Expanded*" property which would look as follows in C#Script;

```
// Setting items within the tree using wItem->Item 
var routingRules = tree["wItems"]["Item"]("Routing Rules");
// Lower level objects use wItems->Item->Items->Item
var L2Branches = routingRules[Items][Item]("Level 2 branches");
Log["Message"](routingRules["Expanded"]); // returns True or False 
var isExpanded = routingRules["Expanded"];
Log["Message"]("value of isExpanded",isExpanded);
```

Or in Javascript;

```
// Setting items within the tree using wItem->Item 
var routingRules = tree.wItems.Item("Routing Rules");
// Lower level objects use wItems->Item->Items->Item
var L2Branches = routingRules.Items.Item.("Level 2 branches");
Log.Message(routingRules.Expanded); // returns True or False 
var isExpanded = routingRules.Expanded;
Log.Message.("value of isExpanded",isExpanded);
```

The TestComplete documentation has further information on the ["*wExpanded*" Property](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/reference/test-objects/members/tree-view/wexpanded-property-win32treeview-control.html) ,the ["*Item*" Object interface](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/reference/test-objects/members/tree-view-item-collection/item-property-treeviewitemcollection-object.html) and the [JTreeItem Properties](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/reference/test-objects/controls/desktop/java/tree-item/properties.html) to which it gives access, including "*Expanded*".